# How to filter out one value in a column to one value in another column, but calculate one to many values in another columns

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Below is the original pyspark dataframe:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  Idx| Name|Value|Wight|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|Peter|  123|  0.1|
|    B|Peter|  234|  0.1|
|    B| Mary|  287|  0.1|
|    B|Jason|  243|  0.1|
|    C| Mary|  109|  0.1|
|    D|David|  231|  0.1|
|    D| Sean|  101|  0.1|
|    D|  Tim|  238|  0.1|
|    E|  Ken|  910|  0.1|
|    E|  Jim|  112|  0.1|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

As Idx **A** and **C** only match with one name, but idx B, D, E match with several names separtely. So I want to keep idx b, d, e and multiple their value and weight to a new column named 'result'.

Below is the desired output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|  Idx| Name|Value|Wight|Result|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|    B|Peter|  234|  0.1|  23.4|
|    B| Mary|  287|  0.1|  28.7|
|    B|Jason|  243|  0.1|  24.3|
|    D|David|  231|  0.1|  23.1|
|    D| Sean|  101|  0.1|  10.1|
|    D|  Tim|  238|  0.1|  23.8|
|    E|  Ken|  910|  0.1|  91.0|
|    E|  Jim|  112|  0.1|  11.2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Actually, I don't know what this can be called so I cannot find a solution online. I only want to calculate the result of one idx to multiple name columns.

Comment: I will be better if you provide the Spark DataFrame constructor.

Comment: Are you trying to sort of the frequency of `Idx` then drop duplicates on `Name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` and `apply` function in Pandas to get desired output.

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.value_counts() > 1]
df1['Result'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['Value'] * row['Wight'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to filter rows with duplicated `Idx` values and perform `Value * Wight` in new column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

...
df.exceptAll(df.dropDuplicates(['Idx'])).withColumn("Result", col("Value") * col("Weight"))
```